# Error when update apt-get to add backtrack repository

Tags: ubuntu

i have signature error when i want to add backtrack repositories to my Ubuntu 13.10 by apt-get update after
adding repositories to this file /etc/apt/source.list
what shall i do to solve it?
error:

> http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AB6DA34B475A6B7F

help me please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do that

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AB6DA34B475A6B7F
```

And do the apt-get update again.

Answer (score 0):

I find this way to solve this problem.

command:

> wget -q http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/backtrack.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -